# Возможно ли настроить Gradle для автогенерации dimen?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Есть приложение. Я прописываю в нем размеры в values-sw330dp/dimens.xml и дублирую их в sw266dp/dimens.xml с коэффициентом 0.8. Хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс. Возможно ли настроить Gradle так, чтобы он брал значения из sw330dp и создавал точно такие же в sw266dp с коэффициентом 0.8?

Comment: вообще скрипт gradle пишется на языке groovy, так что теоретически наверное можно, а практически - не думаю, что кому то приходила такая идея до вас. Проблема уже в том, что при каждом запуске\отладке оно все будет заново генерироваться каждый раз, а тут и так скорость компиляции проекта оставляет желать лучшего

Comment: @pavlofff, ну это ведь в любом случае, быстрее, чем вручную. А есть ли хоть какие-то мысли/наброски по практической реализации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) умеет фильтровать файлы. Сложнее (но можно) будет найти нужные значения в sw330dp/dimens.xml. Вместо этого я предлагаю вынести значения куда-нибудь в gradle.properties и подставлять их в оба dimens.xml файла с нужными коэффициентами:

```
task sw330dp_dimens(type: Copy) {
    from('template') {
       include '**/dimens.xml'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [value: vvv])
    }
    into 'sw330dp'
}

task sw266dp_dimens(type: Copy) {
    from('template') {
       include '**/dimens.xml'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [value: vvv*0.8])
    }
    into 'sw266dp'
}
```